# Mathematical Transcription Software

Tags: soft-question, math-software

In light of much of the new legislation that is being created in North America, my university has asked me to transcribe some of my online video content that I have created for my students.

Does anyone have any experience with transcribing mathematical videos and if so, what software/setup do you use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what new legislation are you referring to?

Comment: When you refer to "transcribing", do you mean  making available a written (typed) transcription of the content of your videos?  Are you thus referring legislation,  in the US, (and/or elsewhere) like the US ADA?

Comment: Specifically referring to AODA in Ontario but I suspect there are parallels to the US ADA (though I admit to not having read the latter). By transcribing, I really mean 'transcription with the intent of adding closed captioning' - perhaps this is easy after transcribing but I'm not sure. I'm really more curious as to how to typeset the math in a video properly/easily with closed captioning.

Comment: Are you referring to speech recognition software for mathematics, like MathTalk?